# 7z "is not supported archive" while updating an archive

Tags: archive, compression, 7zip

While updating an archive we are getting this error:

```
$ 7za u -pPasswored -mhe=on -r -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m '-x!temp' filename.7z  /home/software
Error: XXXXXXX.7z is not supported archive
System error:
Operation not permitted
```

What does it mean? How can we fix it?

Comment: Reviewers: The OS being used here [is actually CentOS](http://askubuntu.com/q/491129/22949#comment656873_491132), so we should close this question as off-topic. **user340869:** Questions that are about CentOS and not about Ubuntu [are off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions). You should instead ask this someplace CentOS is supported, like the [CentOS forums](http://centos.org/modules/newbb/) or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). (Or, based on [Frantique's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/491132/22949), you may be able to find a solution by searching for *p7zip centos*.) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
 sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

If you have it already, take a look to the `operation not permitted` part of error message. It seems that you don't have sufficient permissions in that directory to write temp files. 7zip needs it. Please give write access to that directory!

Comment: We are using CentOS 6 and 5 and also full (777) permissions for that directory."in CentOS is there any  package `p7zip-full`"

Comment: Sorry, but why are you asking in AskUbuntu instead of CentOS's forums?